# Moving non-local player from local player with Mirror Networking

Tags: unity, multiplayer, unet, mirror-networking

i am using mirror networking which is based on UNet. I can move non local objects easly by assigning their authority to the local player and move them, but i can't assign/remove authority for other player's in the game, therefore i can't directly change their velocity. Any ideas how can i change other non local player's velocity from local player ?

Comment: Have you considered sending a message to that other client, requesting that it move the character under its own authority?

Comment: I am very newbie about networking, i will look into it thanks @DMGregory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i don't know if this is the proper way but i have managed to solved this by sending message to server and server sending that message back to the clients. Clients can act (move in my case) upon that.